# Each limit represents the derivative of some function $f$ at some number $a.$ State $f$ and $a$ in each case.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> The limit
> $$L=\lim\limits _{h \to 0} \frac{(1+h)^{10} - 1}{h}.$$

To be honest I’m not sure what this question is asking for and I’m not sure how to begin solving it.

I know $f(a) = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(a+h) - f(a)}{h}$. Direct substitution of $h=0$ won’t work here because there will be a zero in the bottom. That’s the obvious part. But I got confused because even if you factor out the numerator, and cancel you’ll still get a zero in the denominator.

Comment: If you expect people to put in the effort to answer a question, then it is polite to put in some effort yourself. In particular, don't just say "I’m not sure how to begin solving it". The standard place to start is to look at your notes or book to see if there are related questions with worked solutions. Did you do this?

Comment: Yes I did. Is there a way to link pictures here?

Answer (score 2):

Solution 1:

Rewrite the original limit:
$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{(1+h)^{10}-1}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{(1+h)^{10}-(1+0)^{10}}{h-0}$$

Should be really easy to continue from here by the definition of derivative. Let $f(x)=(1+x)^{10}$ .

Solution 2:

Expand $(1+x)^{10}$ using binomial theorem, and then you can cancel out the $h$ at both the numerator and the denominator, allowing you to compute the limit.

Comment: Try not to answer questions when someone dumps one here, like the above, with no effort. It is more helpful to get them to do some work themselves (which is why people often ask "what have you tried?"). Also, it is not unlikely that this is their assessed homework, so giving them the complete answer is a kick in the teeth to the rest of their class.

Comment: @user1729 Understandable. My bad. Should I delete it or just edit my answer?

Comment: Deletion is probably better.

Comment: Please do not make assumptions about me. My teacher does not give assesed homework for just this reason. I am asking because I didn’t know where to start. You can take my word for it or you can not. But please do not treat me as a cheater because I am not. Student 1058 I’m not sure if you are still here, but I thank you for actually trying to help.

Comment: @user165349 If you do not want people to assume things, don't just say "I am not that", but *show them*. Make an effort. Explain what you tried (and did you look at your notes or book to see if there are related questions with worked solutions?). Use [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) to make your maths look pretty.

Comment: Yes I just told the other user that I did. Is there a way to link pictures here? If I can’t do that, must MathJax be downloaded.

Comment: @user165349 No need to download anything. Basically you just put dollars around your maths, so `$2+3$` becomes $2+3$ and `$L=\lim _{h \to 0} \frac{(1+h)^{10} - 1}{h}$` becomes $L=\lim _{h \to 0} \frac{(1+h)^{10} - 1}{h}$. You can also click on "edit" to see how the MathJax in other posts is written. (I updated the link in my above comment to a nicer introduction.)

Comment: Ok! Give me like 10 minutes to figure out how to write this out...

Comment: Ok this is what I did @user1729 ... I know f(a) = \lim as h approaches 0 is  (f(a+h) - f(a))/(h). Direct substitution won’t work here because there will be a zero in the bottom. That’s the obvious part. But I got confused because even if you factor out the numerator, and cancel you’ll still get a zero in the denominator. Also sorry this is not in math Jax format yet, I still need to learn what the other symbols mean.

Comment: @user165349 Okay, great. I've edited what you wrote into the question. You can click "edit" to see the code I used (and also to edit what I wrote if it isn't what you meant).

Comment: Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

The general form for the definition of derivative at $x=x_0$ is

$$\lim _{x \to x_0} \frac{f(x) - f(x_0)}{x-x_0}=\lim _{h=x-x_0 \to 0 } \frac{f(x_0+h) - f(x_0)}{h}$$

and comparing with the given expression

$$\lim _{h \to 0} \frac{(1+h)^{10} - 1}{h}$$

we deduce that

- $f(x_0+h)=(1+h)^{10}$
- $f(x_0)=1$

therefore in general

$$f(x)=(1+(x-x_0))^{10}+c$$